# Facebook unity sdk: is it possible to send friend invites/app requests to non app users?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm working with the official facebook sdk and example scene for unity and am sending app requests using : FB.AppRequest() which returns a list of friends to send invites to.

However no matter what I try, I only get a list of friends associated with the app and cannot see any other friends who haven't played the app.

I have even tried setting the 'app_non_user' filter, but this makes no difference.

I have read on the Invitable_Friends api, but am not sure how this would be implemented in the unity sdk.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app must be approved by Facebook to get people's friends lists beyond people using the app. Look in the developers.facebook.com section to find how to do this. I haven't done this, but a game I worked on needed to do this.

Getting approved involves sending your app and it goes through an approval process.

Here's the relevant bit:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

"If your app is a game and has a presence on Facebook Canvas:

You can use the requests Dialog and set filters=app_non_users to filter the dialog to only show people who don't use the app."

Comment: Do you mean getting approved for facebook's app center? Will this allow users to automatically see all their friends when sending a request?Facebooks documentation says user_friends only returns friends who have used the app, will this still be a problem?